# Pandas - How to select by true index after dropping some rows?

Tags: python, pandas

This line `df.iloc[[13]]` lets me select the 13'th row in the dataframe. But my dataframe looks like this

[image]

meaning the 0th row has the index 13. How do I select using the index i.e. `df.index[13]`. I do not wish to reset the indices of my dataframe.

Comment: Are you looking for `df.loc[13]` ?

Comment: I am guessing you want to use the  index with label based indexing instead of loc? , try `df.iloc[[df.index.get_loc(13)]]` ? however, you dont need that since `loc` lets you index by label, not by position of index which is `iloc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select by the index, use `.loc`

```
df.loc[13]
```

Answer (score 1):

try using df.loc[["13"]] this may help you out

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer so anyone can use it in similar situation by knowing what the solution about.